# Resize the image with in Button tag odoo

Tags: html, xml, odoo

I have created a button in XML. when adding the static image to it. I see the image is bigger than the button string added.

Code snippet in XML for the button:

```
 <div class="form_button_small"> <button name="button_price_plan" type="object"
                                    string="Normal Plan" style="width:100%%; height:70px;"
                                            icon="/ra/static/src/img/rsz-price.png"/>
```

How do we reduce the size of image which is compatible with image string.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using this way:

```
<button type="object" name="some_action"><img src="/module_name/static/images/Transfer.svg" style="height: 25px;margin-left: 10px;"/></button>
```

Hope this will work for you.